# Incorrect IsAbstract value in a referenced XmlSchemaElement

Tags: c#, .net, xsd

I'm working with an XML schema that contains abstract element definitions, such as

```
<element name="AbstractX" type="some:Type" abstract="true"/>
```

When loading this schema in an `XmlSchemaSet`, I can find this element in its `GlobalElements` and see that it has the `IsAbstract` property set to `true`. So far so good.

However, this element is also referenced in a type like this

```
<complexType name="ReferencingX">
    <complexContent>
        <extension base="some:otherBaseType">
            <sequence>
                <element ref="some:AbstractX"/>
            </sequence>
        </extension>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

In the parsed XmlSchemaSet, when I navigate to the element through the complex type definition, it has `IsAbstract` set to `false`.

Is there some reason for that, or is it a bug in `System.Xml.Schema`?

(I've simplified the XSD for the sake of brevity, the schema in question is [AIXM](http://www.aixm.aero/public/standard_page/download.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bug.

What you're looking at in your code is a **reference** to an (abstract) element; references cannot be marked abstract (section [3.3.2 XML Schema Part 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element), abstract is applicable only when the schema is the parent of the element).

You simply need to:

- check if el.RefName.IsEmpty; in your case, it is not (since you used the ref attribute).
- navigate to the appropriate definition in GlobalElements[el.RefName], cast the value to an XmlSchemaElement, and then check its IsAbstract property (which will be true in your case).

This should address your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but can you elaborate on why "references cannot be marked abstract"? It is an XmlSchemaElement, all other information is taken from the referenced element, why not this?

Comment: @voidengine, the spec says so (I've updated my answer with the reference). It is incorrect to state `all other information is taken from the referenced element`. For e.g., the SchemaTypeName information is **not** available on the element particle using @ref, you have to navigate to the referenced (global) element as said in my answer. Indeed, you may get the ElementSchemaType populated, but do not forget that is a post-schema-validation infoset property. My personal observation is that the API was written to adhere as much as possible to the spec: where the spec says not allowed...

Comment: (cont'd), the API doesn't populate it: type (cannot be used on a ref), abstract (will always return false), etc.